# Pipe between bash 'yes' command and netcat breaks with nc: Address already in Use

Tags: linux, bash, networking, scripting, netcat

I'm trying to write a simple script that loads my localhost network by setting up a netcat listener and piping random data to netcat broadcaster.  My script is simple:

```
nc -l 2020 > /dev/null &
yes SOME_VERY_LARGE_STRING | nc localhost 2020 > /dev/null
```

Running each of those commands in different terminal windows has the desired effect.  However, running from a bash script results in some data being transmitted before a `SIGPIPE` signal being sent to `yes`.  This broken pipe can be verified by replacing the above with:

```
strace yes SOME_VERY_LARGE_STRING | nc localhost 2020 > /dev/null
```

which results in the following output:

```
execve("/usr/bin/yes", ["yes", "SOME_VERY_LARGE_STRING"], [/* 75 vars */]nc: Address already in use
) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1d53000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f04f185b000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff4531cc20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib/tls", 0x7fff4531cc20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff4531cc20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/eddy/OpenSource/ros_packages/devel/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/opt/ros/indigo/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/ros/indigo/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff4531cc20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/ros/indigo/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/ros/indigo/lib/tls", 0x7fff4531cc20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff4531cc20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/ros/indigo/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=165844, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 165844, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f04f1832000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P \2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1857312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3965632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f04f1272000
mprotect(0x7f04f1430000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f04f1630000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1be000) = 0x7f04f1630000
mmap(0x7f04f1636000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f04f1636000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f04f1831000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f04f182f000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f04f182f740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f04f1630000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x605000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f04f185d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f04f1832000, 165844)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1d53000
brk(0x1d74000)                          = 0x1d74000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7216688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 7216688, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f04f0b90000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f04f185a000
write(1, "SOME_VERY_LARGE_STRING\nSOME_VERY"..., 4096) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=11094, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

It would appear that `netcat` is failing with Address already in use.  Why would that happen?

Comment: Did you kill the first `nc -l` process before running the script? Only one process can listen on port 2020 at a time.

Comment: Also, there's a `TIME_WAIT` state that keeps a port reserved for a few minutes after the old server has exited. In C you can get around it by using `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option, I don't know if `netcat` does this.

Comment: Never mind that, I just traced `nc -l` and it does use `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: Yes I killed the original `nc -l` before running the script

Comment: Use `lsof -i :2020` to see what's using the port.

Comment: does the `nc` not start before `yes` tries to write? try putting a `sleep 1` in-between?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have added a sleep 1 and seen no change